# Change selected item from inside onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following select box:

```
var sval=1;
function foo(v) {
    sval=Number(v);
}
...
<select name="sval" onchange="
   if (confirm('...?')) foo(this.value); else $(this).val(sval);">
  <option value="1">1
  <option value="2">2
  <option value="3">3
```

The idea is to confirm the selected item change. If not confirmed to change back to the old value.

- if confirm returns true, all is working as expected
- if confirm returns false, then the select always gets value 1, regardles of `sval`

Why changing the selected item does not work from inside the onchange handler?

EDIT: The following code based on ejay_francisco's answer does the proper job:

http://jsfiddle.net/4wCQh/33/

```
var vals = 1;
$("#svalue").change(function() {
    if (confirm('...?'))
         vals=Number(this.value);
    else
         $(this).val(vals);   
});
```

but its not clear what is the reason that the inline code `$(this).val(sval)` resets the select to 1

Comment: else part is not neccessary

Comment: @bbonev dude i updated my answer please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason the code is not working.

It came out that there are differences between execution in fiddle and browser which made tracking the problem harder.

In the inline code of the onchange event a variable with the same name as `name="sval"` gets defined and because the name is the same with the integer variable from the global context, the code is not using the proper value to change select's value.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code and this is how i've done it

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wCQh/35/) :

Javascript :

```
$( "#svalue" ).change(function() {
    if (confirm('...?')) {
            vals =$('#svalue').val();
     $('#svalue').val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    }else{
      $('#svalue').val(vals);
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<select id="svalue">
    <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
```

**EDITED** :

here's how its done inline : working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7zLT/)

HTML:

```
<select name="sval" onchange="if (confirm('...?')) {foo(this.value);sval=(this.value);} else $(this).val(sval);">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
```

Javascript :

```
var sval=1;
function foo(v) {
   $('#svalue').val(v);
}
```

apparently you forgot to change the value of `sval` to whatever the user has previously clicked. the code is `sval=(this.value);` on the `onchange` part.

Comment: Initially the variable sval=1 and selected item is 1; after changing selecting item to 2, if confirmed both should change; afterwards if 3 is selected but not confirmed, both variable and selected item should go back to 2.

Comment: there. edited it. now it goes back to previous value

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4wCQh/33/ - yep, that does what I want, but still does not answer my question why the inline code is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try

I think else part is not neccessary

Change to

```
<select name="sval" onchange="
   if (confirm('...?')) foo(this.value);">
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` does not change the selected item; the idea is to reselect the old value, if not confirmed. After confirmed change to 3, the value of sval becomes 3, then changing to 2 and clicking no on confirm dialog should go back to 3 and it goes to 1...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is absolutely horrible.

When ever you inline JavaScript events on elements it just looks ugly.

Why are you wanting to set the select value to the value it has as the currently selected value?

Could you just skip this `$(this).val(sval = this.value;);` and only have this `sval = this.value;`

I'm just really a huge fan as to keeping the code and values to a bare minimum where variables are not needed and also where code is not needed.

Give this a shot.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var sval = 1;
    var foo = function () {

   if(confirm('...?')) {

      $(this).val(sval = this.value);
        }
        else
        {
         $(this).val(sval);
        }
    };

    setTimeout(function () {

        document.getElementById('sval').onchange = foo;
    }, 100);

</script>

<select id="sval">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```